# What's the best way for foreigners outside of the UK to get to an English Premier League game?

Tags: tickets, uk, events, sports-events, football

I recently got a bonus from my company and want to fly to England for a weekend to watch some soccer. It would be great to go to a big game, however I know getting my hands on tickets can be really tricky. What would be a way to achieve this?

Specifically I'm a Liverpool fan, but I'd appreciate general advice...

Comment: This may be off topic, but I'm not sure where else to ask it. I believe it's not unusual to travel to a place just for a sporting event.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I also think this is off-topic. Your question is not related to travelling to the event, but to purchasing tickets for it. If you were to ask, for example, how to secure transportation to a place that is known to be hosting a big event, that might make a good question.

Comment: I think this could be allowed, because travelling for sporting events *is* something travellers do, and finding EPL tickets *is* going to be hard for a foreign resident. Perhaps it could be rephrased though to ask 'How can a foreign visitor watch an EPL game...' instead of 'Where can I buy...'

Comment: Agree. As it stands it's off topic (as per [faq]), but could be reworded.  Otherwise we'll have to allow 'where can I buy a ski pass / ticket to the Opera.  Currently it's basically a shopping question, which we try to avoid.  I'm going to take the liberty to reword it as per Ankur's suggestion, and then Kevin, if you can let us know if you're ok with the resulting question.  Cheers.

Comment: if the UK system works like the Dutch, it's impossible to purchase tickets unless you are affiliated with a fanclub for one of the teams, and can then only purchase tickets for games featuring that team (there are some exceptions like for corporate sponsors).

Comment: There are, in fact, travel agents who specialise in this market, so I'd say it's definitely on topic.

Comment: This is definitly an on-topic question. There are loads of people who travel to see sporting events in foreign countries with teams that aren't from their country. If the question was "How do I book a safari in South Africa?" it would be on topic, so I can't see "How do I book a football match in England" can't be.

Comment: I once became member of one of the PL clubs to have the right to purchase a ticket. Well it worked but had 25 pounds extra costs for the 1yr membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for [eticketing.co.uk](https://www.eticketing.co.uk/muticketsandmembership/default.aspx?__utma=1.833502665.1315900708.1318495317.1323323173.4&__utmb=1.4.10.1323323173&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1315900708.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=13749815).

Tried to buy ticket from ManUtd website and it redirects to [eticketing.co.uk](https://www.eticketing.co.uk/muticketsandmembership/default.aspx?__utma=1.833502665.1315900708.1318495317.1323323173.4&__utmb=1.4.10.1323323173&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1315900708.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=13749815)
This website allows you to view the seat location and if there is no available seats, it can notify you if there is more seat available.[image]

Note that you should arrive early in the stadium since usually they separate the tribune for the home and visiting team.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest someone like [The Fanatics](http://www.thefanatics.com/), who a group of us expats used to buy tickets.  They tend to follow the Fulham games, but if you time it right for when Fulham is playing Liverpool, you could be in ;)

Otherwise [Ticketmaster](http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/) is another option for events of all types, including the football, although possibly you'll need a UK address to have them posted to.  The Fanatics were great as we booked through the website, and just met their group at the gate, and all sat together - with really great seats too!